# Unable to create more than 1000 files (C++ program)

Tags: c, file

I have been trying to make a program in C/C++ that creates files until the process is stopped.
The file names start from 0 and follow an arithmetic sequence.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

long cifre(long x) //returns the number of digits a number has
{
    int nr = 0;
    while (x != 0)
    {
        x = x/10;
        nr++;
    }
    return nr;
}

int main()
{
    long i=0;
    FILE* g;
    char* v;
    char buffer[1025];
    int j=0;

    for (j=0;j<1024;j++)
        buffer[j] = 'x';

    while (1)
    {   
        v = (char*)malloc(cifre(i)+10);
        snprintf(v,sizeof(v),"%ld",i);
        g = fopen(v,"w");
        fprintf(g,"%s",buffer);
        free(v);
        fclose(g);
        i++;
    }    
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that the program creates only 1000 files.

Comment: What is your filesystem? Which OS are you using?

Comment: It's really a problem of your filesystem. I've run your program for a while and then terminate it by ^C. I get: `ls | wc -l
378872` — much more than 1000 files. BTW, you don't make `buffer[1024]=0`, so it works wrong!

Comment: @PatrickB. ext4, Ubuntu 12.10

Comment: @Robert frost, 32bit? That's why in your case `sizeof(v) == 4` and program doesn't work, and in case of 64bit `sizeof(v) == 8` and it produce more files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `sizeof(v)` in the call to sprintf is the size of a char pointer, in your case probably 4, which means that the formatted string will contain at most 3 characters, or the numbers from 0 to 999. To fix this use the same length you used to allocate memory:

```
    size_t len = cifre(i)+10;
    v = (char*)malloc(len);
    snprintf(v,len,"%ld",i);
```

Answer (score 1):

`snprintf(v,sizeof(v)` doesn't make much sense because `sizeof(v)` returns the size of the pointer (`v` is `char*`), not the size of the dynamically allocated array. And so `snprintf()` is limited to only printing `sizeof(v)`-1 characters, or 3 digits and the NUL string terminator. 3 digits give you values from 000 to 999, exactly 1000.